# Sphinx restructuredtext code appears as mailto hyperlink

Tags: python-sphinx, mailto, restructuredtext

I am trying to write documentation in rst and build webpages using Sphinx. The issue I am having is that code with the `@` symbol in it is turned into a mailto link by Sphinx.

```
This is the command prompt:

    pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

How do I stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
This is the command prompt:

.. code-block:: bash

    pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```